# A question about looping and creating/joining tables

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

My code is meant to order a table called Football (imported csv2) and then, using a for loop, go through the data and return the row number of the start year and end year.

```
Football[order(Football$Year),]

start_year <- min(Football$Year)
end_year <- max(Football$Year)

for (i in 1:nrow(Football)
{
  if (Football$Year[i] = start_year)
  {
    row_of_start <- i
  }
  if (Football$Year[i] = end_year)
  {
    row_of_end <- i
  }
}
```

This produces the following error:

```
> if (Football$Year[1] = start_year) row_of_start <- 1
Error: unexpected '=' in "if (Football$Year[1] ="
```

I appreciate there are probably ways of doing this without a for loop (which I would be very appreciative to know) although I would also like to know how to make the for loop work (to further my understanding).

Comment: USe `==` instead of `=` i.e. `Football$Year[1] == start_year`

Comment: Apart from @akrun's right comment, there is no need for loops: `row_of_start<- which(Football$Year  == start_year)` and the same for `row_of_end`.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the loop entirely using `which()`. This will usually be faster and more legible:

```r
# Create example data
set.seed(123)
Football <- data.frame(Year = sample(1990:2000, size = 10),
                       foo = sample(letters, size = 10))

# Sort the data as you have done
Football_sort <- Football[order(Football$Year), ]

# Get the row numbers of the min and max (start and end years)
which(with(Football_sort, Year == min(Year)))
#> [1] 1
which(with(Football_sort, Year == max(Year)))
#> [1] 10
```

Depending upon what you **actually** want to do, you can skip the ordering step as well. Both of the below depend upon the `dplyr` package to work.

If you just want the start and end year rows rather than their row numbers:

```r
library(dplyr)

Football %>%
  filter(Year %in% c(min(Year), max(Year)))

#>   Year foo
#> 1 2000   e
#> 2 1990   d
```

If you want the "year number" of the start and end year:

```r
Football %>%
  summarise(start_year = 1,
            end_year = max(Year) - min(Year))
#>   start_year end_year
#> 1          1       10
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a few alternative things to consider. Cheers!